# how to insert datetime into the SQL Database table?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, c#-3.0

How can I insert datetime into the SQL Database table ?
Is there a way to insert this query through the insert command in C# / .NET?

Comment: In this discussion is solved for datetime in SQL server

http://stackoverflow.com/a/12957690/2120484

Answer (score 114, accepted):

DateTime values should be inserted as if they are strings surrounded by single quotes:

```
'20100301'
```

SQL Server allows for many accepted date formats and it should be the case that most development libraries provide a series of classes or functions to insert datetime values properly. However, if you are doing it manually, it is important to distinguish the date format using `DateFormat` and to use generalized format:

```
Set DateFormat MDY --indicates the general format is Month Day Year

Insert Table( DateTImeCol )
Values( '2011-03-12' )
```

By setting the dateformat, SQL Server now assumes that my format is `YYYY-MM-DD` instead of `YYYY-DD-MM`.

[SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

SQL Server also recognizes a generic format that is always interpreted the same way: `YYYYMMDD` e.g. `20110312`.

If you are asking how to insert the current date and time using T-SQL, then I would recommend using the keyword `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. For example:

```
Insert Table( DateTimeCol )
Values( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
```

Comment: Is that correct? You `Set DateFormat MDY`, but later you say that SQL Server now assumes my format is `YYY-MM-DD`. Why doesn't SQL Server expect your format to match the `Set DateFormat` and look for `MM-DD-YYYY`? I'm not saying it's wrong (I don't know), but it seems counter-intuative.

Comment: @JerryOL - The `Set DateFormat MDY` only determines how SQL interprets the the order of month and day, not the exact format. You can try it for yourself. If you call `Set DateFormat DMY`, `2011-03-12` is Dec 3rd. If you call `Set DateFormat MDY`, that same date is March 12th.

Comment: @JerryOL - Btw, I could have also used `YMD` or `YDM` and achieved the same effect however I find that those formats are only useful if you are not passing the four digit year.

Answer (score 15):

You will need to have a [datetime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752.aspx) column in a table.  Then you can do an insert like the following to insert the current date:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values (GetDate())
```

If it is not today's date then you should be able to use a string and [specify the date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values (Convert(DateTime,'19820626',112)) --6/26/1982
```

You do not always need to convert the string either, often you can just do something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (MyDate) Values ('06/26/1982')
```

And SQL Server will figure it out for you.

Answer (score 8):

if you got actuall time in mind `GETDATE()` would be the function what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

DateTime values should be inserted as if they are strings surrounded by single quotes
`'20201231'`
**but** in many cases they need to be casted explicitly to datetime `CAST(N'20201231' AS DATETIME)` to avoid bad execution plans with CONVERSION_IMPLICIT warnings that affect negatively the performance. Hier is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T(D DATETIME)

--wrong way
INSERT INTO dbo.T (D) VALUES ('20201231'), ('20201231')
```

[image: Warnings in the execution plan]

```
--better way
INSERT INTO dbo.T (D) VALUES (CAST(N'20201231' AS DATETIME)), (CAST(N'20201231' AS DATETIME))
```

[image: No warnings]

Answer (score -1):

```
myConn.Execute "INSERT INTO DayTr (dtID, DTSuID, DTDaTi, DTGrKg) VALUES (" & Val(txtTrNo) & "," & Val(txtCID) & ", '" & Format(txtTrDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "' ," & Val(Format(txtGross, "######0.00")) & ")"
```

Done in vb with all text type variables.