# How to add date and time as a column to a database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to have date and time columns in my database. I chose `DATE` type for date but to only get time which type should I give and while writing a record for it in which format should I write?

Edit: I am using SQL Server.

Comment: Which database, Oracle, Mysql, SQL Server, something else?

Comment: DATETIME instead of DATE

Comment: Go with `ISO` for your dbms. [check out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259188%28SQL.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @user1463542 SQl server? or TSQL?

Comment: [Here is another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287427/how-to-insert-datetime-into-the-sql-database-table) if this answers, please close the question.

Comment: There is no DATETIME data type in Sql. I am gonna enter the time manually so I want to learn which datatype i should use for time while I create my table.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21523/discussion-between-user1463542-and-boncodigo)

Comment: SQL just stands for "Structured Query Language", a definition of how you can communicate with relational databases. Your issue right now is with the database management system you're using, if you're using Microsoft SQL Server, there is definitely a datetime. What management system are you using, exact name/version etc? Data types can vary based on the system, and still be SQL.

Comment: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

Answer (score 2):

Try `DateTime`, contains both a date and time component.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

EDIT: Now that you say you're using Oracle, it does have time support in the Date value it seems, though I'm not an oracle expert. I found this if it helps:
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html

Comment: There are comments above, where many **have suggested the same!** Like GeorgesD's comment etc.

Comment: Yeah, it's a very basic question that three seconds of googling could answer if you didn't know SQL. Any reason to just comment vs. answer? I was just trying to help close out the question.