# convert varchar(ddmmyyyy) to date format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I convert, for example, ddmmyyyy which is a varchar(8) to date format(dd/mm/yyyy)?

I have a stored procedure which accepts a date varchar(8) parameter.

I want to convert it to date format before inserting into database.
I tried to use

```
INSERT INTO mytable(createdDate) VALUES (CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), @date), 106));
```

An error:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

createdDate column is type : date

Comment: why are you converting varchar again to varchar? is Convert(date,@date,106) not working?

Comment: You don't need to convert the varchar to date while inserting in to db. It will automatically handled by db.
INSERT INTO MyTable (createdDate) Values ('dd/mm/yyyy') and sql server will figure it out for you.

Comment: follow this link for reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5287427/how-to-insert-datetime-into-the-sql-database-table

Comment: @jadavparesh06 it actually does! i didnt know. thanks!

Comment: @edward : I added a 2nd example to my answer that is a slight improvement :).

Comment: @Mukund : the CONVERT() by itself can't work as there is no style number for "ddmmyyyy". And 106 is actually "dd mon yyyy", and this data is definitely not using "mon" (e.g. JAN instead of 01).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ddmmyyyy` is not a valid date format. You need to first make that string into something that can be parsed as a `DATE` / `DATETIME`. The quickest way might be to simply `SUBSTRING` the pieces into a `mm/dd/yyyy` format. That does convert successfully. But you have a `VARCHAR(8)`. So you either need to increase that to be `VARCHAR(10)` (or better yet, just `CHAR(10)`), or declare a local variable to hold the altered value.

For example:

```sql
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(8); -- input parameter
SET @Date = '25032014';

DECLARE @Date2 CHAR(10);
SET @Date2 = SUBSTRING(@Date, 3, 2)
             + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Date, 1, 2)
             + '/' + SUBSTRING(@Date, 5, 4);

SELECT @Date2, CONVERT(DATE, @Date2);
-- 03/25/2014     2014-03-25
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, I found a slightly simpler way. I started out with this method but realized that it did not work with `ddmmyyyy` as opposed to `mmddyyyy`. I somehow missed that there was an appropriate date style number for `dd/mm/yyyy`. So, simply adding two slashes to the incoming string and then calling `CONVERT` does work, but only if you use `103` as the "style". And like the first solution, it requires either changing the incoming parameter to be `VARCHAR(10)` or `CHAR(10)` instead of `VARCHAR(8)`, or creating a local variable to be `CHAR(10)`.

```sql
DECLARE @Date VARCHAR(8); -- input parameter
SET @Date = '25032014';

DECLARE @Date2 CHAR(10);
SET @Date2 = STUFF(STUFF(@Date, 3, 0, '/'), 6, 0, '/');

SELECT @Date2, CONVERT(DATE, @Date2, 103); -- 103 = dd/mm/yyyy
-- 25/03/2014     2014-03-25
```

Conversion "styles" can be found on the MSDN page for [CAST and CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).